# syncfusion Data integration platform

Tags: bigdata, syncfusion

I'm trying the  Syncfusion data integration platform and I'm not able to import a log file.can anyone help me? How to import a .log file in Syncfusion Data integration platform?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that you are trying to fetch log file details using Syncfusion Data Integration Platform. Provided sample data flow and documentation to fetch details from log file and storing resultant data on files based on the log message type.

Please download the [Monitoring Log file](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/Monitoring_sample-1426279567) sample

For upload sample into Data Integration Platform, please refer Syncfusion help [link](https://help.syncfusion.com/data-integration/getting-started#working-with-templates).

Comment: the log file is located in a remote machine.how can I configure the processor

Comment: Syncfusion Data Integration Platform doesn't have the direct processor to read the remote files. However, we can achieve this by

1. Creating external application(C# or any other executable) to get the remote file and use [ExecuteProcess](https://help.syncfusion.com/data-integration/processors/executeprocess) processor to get the result of an external application in flowfile content.

2. Using [ExecuteScript](https://help.syncfusion.com/data-integration/processors/executescript) processor, we can get the remote files, with available scripts like groovy, python, ruby, etc.